# MVC 5 EF - Error when trying to change Table name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class named "Ciudad". When I want to add a migration to create the datatable, EF uses the name "dbo.Ciudads". I actually wanted the name to be "Ciudades" (with an additional 'e') so I changed it manually.

After updating the databse the table dbo.Ciudades was created successfully. I even created a small script to populate it and it run ok.

However, when I want to query "Ciudades" from the context, I get an exception because it tries to query the table "dbo.Ciudads" (without the additional 'e') which doesn't actually exists. It is an **InvalidOperationException: "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created"**

So I ran "add-migration foo" and it generates the following migration:

```
public partial class foo : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Ciudads", newName: "Ciudades");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Ciudades", newName: "Ciudads");
    }
}
```

It seems strange because in my database I DO have the table exactly as I wanted with the name "Ciudades". Nevertheless, when I try to update the database with this migration, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.

I imagine I get this exception because the table "Ciudads" doesn't exist. Am I correct?

If so, where it is getting that table from? I did a search on the Entire Solution for the word "ciudads" and nothing came up.

Comment: You can try using the `ToTable` annotation above your class, i.e., `[ToTable("Ciudades")]`

Comment: I am actually using FluentAPI and have already done that, but I still get the exception :(

Comment: *"I actually wanted the name to be "Ciudades" (with an additional 'e') so I changed it manually."* This is the place you did it wrong. Instead of changing it manually in the generated migration class, you should have used data annotation / fluent API and regenerate the migration. Now it's too late. All you can do is to generate a new migration (as you did) and remove the code from `Up` and `Down` methods before applying it.

Comment: @IvanStoev you sir are awesome! This was indeed the problem. I deleted everything and started all over again following your suggestion and now it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IvanStoev for the solution.

The problem was that I manually changed the table name in the generated migration class. Later I used FluentAPI to specify the name "Ciudades" but it was to late.
As per @IvanStoev suggestion I deleted everything and created the migrations again, but this time using FluentAPI BEFORE creating the migrations. The table was then generated with the name I intended and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach .

```
 public override void Up()
{
    RenameTable("dbo.Ciudads", "Ciudades");
}

public override void Down()
{
    RenameTable("dbo.Ciudades", "Ciudads");
}
```

Or 
If you want to specify your table name.You can use fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("t_Department");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both and still getting the exception. I can't figure out from where it is taking the name 'Ciudads'. :S

Comment: You can try without dbo.just try with the table name.

RenameTable("Ciudads", "Ciudades");

and please check your table name is same or not.your table name should be Ciudads.

Comment: I tried without the "dbo" and I also have checked many times the actual table name nad it is "Ciudades". I still can't understand where it is getting "Ciudads"

Answer (score -1):

It's probably worth downloading microsoft SQL server management studio dev edition.

Comment: Your answer is more like a comment

Comment: i couldn't comment though. forgive me.

Comment: I am trying to use Code First EF, that's why I didn't follow that approach. But thanks for commenting.